# Don't cache pages WITHOUT a certain cookie - W3 Total Cache for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, cookies, w3-total-cache

I'm struggling with a problem. In the W3 Total Cache plugin there is this option under Page Cache > Advanced > Rejected Cookies. With this option, you can select a cookie and if this cookie is active on a page, that page won't be cached. However, in my case the page should always be cached, except for when the cookie is NOT active. Is this possible to achieve, and if so, how would I do this?

If it helps, the cookie is related to the WeePie Cookie Allow plugin and is activated through an accept button (to give consent to the use of cookies). The cookie notice doesn't popup on cached pages.

Thanks in advance,
Gideon

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a workaround. I added a cookie which should be loaded before the page loads itself. This cookie I added to the 'Rejected Cookies' option in W3 Total Cache. Next up I made it so that if the cookie of the WeePie Cookie Allow plugin was active, this one would be deleted so the page would be cached again.

Code I added to functions.php if anyone were to have the same problem:

```
function AddRemoveCookie(){
$ThatCookie = '1';
setcookie("consentNotGiven", $ThatCookie);

if (isset($_COOKIE['wpca_consent'])) {
    setcookie("consentNotGiven", "", time() - 3600);
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
add_action( "template_redirect", "AddRemoveCookie" );
```